# How to generate under-dispersed Poisson variables in R?

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, simulation

In this article ["generate quasi-poisson distribution random variables"](https://www.r-bloggers.com/generate-quasi-poisson-distribution-random-variable/), it is shown how to use the function `rnbinom` to simulate overdispersed Poisson data:

```r
rqpois <- function(n, mu, theta) rnbinom(n=n, mu=mu, size=mu/(theta-1)).
```

The function `rqpois` works well but it is clearly undefined for values of `theta` less than one. As such, it can only simulate overdispersed data. And it is unclear to me how to modify the function to simulate under-dispersed data.

The empirical context is a series of (iid) competitions where I expect people to see what the others are doing and decide whether to enter or stay out. The count of entrants is what I am interested in. Empirically I found the data are "underdispersed" (i.e., mean >> var).

Comment: quasi-poisson isn't really a distribution (that's why the *quasi*).  Can you tell us more of the context? Why do you expext/need underdispersion? Then we coud model some mechanism that can produce underdispersion. See [this list](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=gsb90&q=Underdispersion%20models%20%20Models%20that%20are%20%E2%80%9Cunder%20the%20radar%E2%80%9D&lookup=0&hl=en) for some papers.    Also https://www.google.no/search?q=underdispersion+site:stats.stackexchange.com&safe=off&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiI7aKh7PvjAhVq-yoKHbWfC7YQrQIoBDADegQICBAO&biw=1280&bih=617

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The context is a competition where I expect people to see what the others are doing and decide whether to enter or stay out. The count of entrants is what I am interested in. Empirically I found the data are "underdispersed" (i.e., mean >> var)

Comment: I observe several independent contests/

Comment: Could you please add this new information to the original question, by editing it?

Comment: Certainly you can have a distribution that is quasi-Poisson (i.e. that is discrete, exponential family with the quasi-Poisson variance function) - you can just take a Poisson variate and multiply by a constant. What you can't have is one of those on the non-negative integers (i.e. there's no quasi-Poisson - aside from the Poisson itself - that is really suitable for counts).

Comment: Re the edit: it sounds like you need something far more complex than a single distribution.  The series of decisions you are observing will be interdependent rather than independent.  If you are interested in counts of such decisions, then it will help to know more about the kinds of dependencies you will introduce in your model.